# Method to toggle camera inputs does not work in reverse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, avfoundation, core-media

I have a video preview layer which shows the video feed from a given input. I want the user to be able to switch camera with single button. The button I have created will switch the camera from the initial back facing camera to the front facing camera but does not work in reverse.

Here is the method:

```
- (IBAction)CameraToggleButtonPressed:(id)sender {
if (_captureSession) {

    NSLog(@"Toggle camera");
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureInput *videoInput = [self videoInput];
    AVCaptureInput *newVideoInput;
    AVCaptureDevicePosition position = [[VideoInputDevice device] position];

    [_captureSession beginConfiguration];
    [_captureSession removeInput:_videoInput];
    [_captureSession removeInput:_audioInput];
    [_captureSession removeOutput:_movieOutput];
    [_captureSession removeOutput:_stillImageOutput];

    //Get new input
    AVCaptureDevice *newCamera = nil;
    if(((AVCaptureDeviceInput*)videoInput).device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
    {
        newCamera = [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
    }
    else
    {
        newCamera = [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    }


    newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:newCamera error:&error];
    if(!newVideoInput || error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating capture device input: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        [self.captureSession addInput:newVideoInput];
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.audioInput];
        [self.captureSession addOutput:self.movieOutput];
        [self.captureSession addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];
    }

    [_captureSession commitConfiguration];
}
}
```

Why is does the button not work in reverse?

Comment: not work means did u get any error ?

Comment: Are you definitely reading the device position you pass into [self cameraWithPosition]?

Comment: '*** Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported.' Am I adding extra input by switching back?